# How can I use require('os') in an Angular 2 Component to get an IP Adress?

Tags: node.js, angular, requirejs

I want to require the following: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html ,
so that I can access the IP-Adress etc. from within an Angular Component.

The following does'nt work though:

```
 const os = require("os");
```

When I log os I I only get this with empty values:

```
{endianness: ƒ, hostname: ƒ, loadavg: ƒ, uptime: ƒ, freemem: ƒ, …}
EOL
:
"↵"
arch
:
ƒ ()
cpus
:
ƒ ()
endianness
:
ƒ ()
freemem
:
ƒ ()
getNetworkInterfaces
:
ƒ ()
homedir
:
ƒ ()
hostname
:
ƒ ()
loadavg
:
ƒ ()
networkInterfaces
:
ƒ ()
platform
:
ƒ ()
release
:
ƒ ()
tmpDir
:
ƒ ()
tmpdir
:
ƒ ()
totalmem
:
ƒ ()
type
:
ƒ ()
uptime
:
ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object
```

In my Node Express Server everything works perfectly and I can use OS as intended.

Edit: If that does'nt work is there any other way to get the IP-Adress and Architecture?

Edit2: Requirement: I cant make any calls to external Websites to get my IP back from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather simple solution to my specific requirements and I wanted to share it to help others in a similar situation:

Using the window object I got all infos without the need to add any packages

```
ipAddress = window.location.host
```

Documentation can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Answer (score 2):

The OS module isn't browser compatible as far as I know.  You can use [sniffr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sniffr) instead to get similar information on the clientside.

Comment: thanks for the reply! A great idea but it didn't provide the information I needed unfortunately. Still thanks and upvote for you!